# How to make UISlider's "track" invisible?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, opacity, uislider

I'm trying to emulate Apple's "Slide to Unlock" feature in my application.  I get to this point (image below), but as you can see the UISlider's "track" is visible and is covering up my text.  Is there a way to change an attribute programmatically that will make the "track" invisible?

[image]

Please let me know if you need any of my code.

Thanks in advance!

EDIT: If I change the slider's alpha to 0, it gets rid of my sliding button, so doing that won't work unless I'm doing it wrong. :)

Comment: It's against Apple's Human Interface Guidelines to replicate the slide to unlock UI.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Actually I just figured it out.  Here's what I did:

```
UIImage *sliderMinimum = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"clearTrack.png"] stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:4 topCapHeight:0];
[slider setMinimumTrackImage:sliderMinimum forState:UIControlStateNormal];
UIImage *sliderMaximum = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"clearTrack.png"] stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:4 topCapHeight:0];
[slider setMaximumTrackImage:sliderMaximum forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

`clearTrack.png` is just a clear slider image I made.

Now I have this:  yay!
[image]

Comment: Thanks btw, I never thought about this method. It's much simpler and faster than the other methods

Comment: Beautifully simple solution for this problem.

Comment: You don't even need to provide an image file - see other answers.

Comment: On an iPad (iOS 8), there is still an image (a shadow perhaps) drawn for the minimum track.

Answer (score 26):

here's an even easier way. No need to create images, just instantiate an empty UIImage class :P

```
UIImage *clearImage = [[UIImage alloc] init];
[self.slider setMinimumTrackImage:clearImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[self.slider setMaximumTrackImage:clearImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Answer (score 6):

There probably isn't a way to hide the track; the "slide to unlock" doesn't behave like a UISlider and is probably a custom control. You *might* be able to hack the slider control, maybe by setting opacity low (0 will make it hidden and it won't receive touches), but if you go that route you will probably have something break after an OS update. Apple doesn't bend over backwards for compatibility like Microsoft does.

The right way to do this is with a custom control. It may seem like more work than using a UISlider, but it's not if you compare it against all the time you have spent and/or will spend hacking a UISlider.

To do it: subclass UIControl. Write your own drawing code to make it look right (you can probably reuse some of whatever you are doing now). Then register for touch events to move the slider handle:

- UIControlEventTouchDown: if it's on the handle, set a "moving" flag
- UIControlEventTouchDragInside: if the moving flag is set, move the handle to the touch position; you can just update an instance variable, call setNeedsDisplay to draw it in the new position.
- UIControlEventTouchUpInside: if moving flag is set, and handle is at end, unlock

If you want to mimic the real unlock handle, play around with it and see how it behaves. You might need to respond to the events differently (what happens if you drag outside the slider path). But you should be able to get the gist of it.

Comment: Great answer, I'll try changing the opacity to a low setting, and if that doesn't work I'll have to try to make my own control.  Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 5):

In Swift:

```
slider.setMinimumTrackImage(UIImage(), forState: .Normal)
slider.setMaximumTrackImage(UIImage(), forState: .Normal)
```

Comment: Good answer, but I recommend you remove everything after the first block of code. It is very tangential to the question, and the TL;DR is that using one or two empty images is fine.

Answer (score 3):

In answer to the stated question, you can set a transparent 1px png for the minimum and maximum track images.

Comment: That's exactly the problem, as you can see in my answer above.

Comment: You must not have seen my answer in time.  Please leave benzado's answer selected.  That approach is correct for what you're trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 3):

Looks like just setting the tint color to clear does it...

```
    [slider setMinimumTrackTintColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    [slider setMaximumTrackTintColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
```

Answer (score 3):

Answer by @Arjay Waran is the best in my opinion.

Heres the Swift 3.0 Version of it.

```
slider.minimumTrackTintColor = UIColor.clear
slider.maximumTrackTintColor = UIColor.clear
```

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

From Story Board:-

select clear color for `Min Track` and `Max Track`

[image]