# How can I hide the UISlider track?

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0, ios4

I've created a slider track that is draw on the actual background of my app and I've also drawn the UISlider thumb image. I know how to set the thumb image for the slider. But how do I hide the UISlider track?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to make UISlider's "track" invisible?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4150903/how-to-make-uisliders-track-invisible)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use a 1px transparent image for the min and max track images.  I [answered this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4150903/how-to-make-uisliders-track-invisible/4151047#4151047) very same question yesterday.

Comment: Looking now, it seems you found your answer there.

Comment: just noticed a few minutes ago :)

Answer (score 24):

If you do not want to use transparent images, you can just set the track images to empty UIImage objects:

```
[slider setMinimumTrackImage:[UIImage alloc] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[slider setMaximumTrackImage:[UIImage alloc] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Comment: I realize this is a separate question, but are there any potential repercussions from not calling init on those images?

Comment: There should be no repercussions of not using init. The init method usually just sets default properties of an object, which are not required for UIImage.

However, using [[UIImage alloc] init] or [UIImage new] will have the same effect in this case.

Answer (score 1):

From Story Board :-

select `clear color` for `Min Track` and `Max Track`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Easy One :

```
[_slider setThumbImage:[UIImage new] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```